# How to add div at the end in django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

In django admin panel, I want to add a div tag at the end of the models change page.
[Below the form mentioned here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcppO.png)

Comment: You can edit the html from 'contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html' - don't edit directly, just copy it to one of your own template directories in admin/. You probably could just override the content block with your own

Comment: But I want to keep that form and after that I want to add a div.